# Code Sniffer single line block problem (Generic.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent)

Tags: php, indentation, phpcodesniffer

I have such code (for example)

```
<?php

while ( false )
    for ( $i = 1; $i < 10; $i++ )
    {
        $k = 1;
        $i = 1;
    }
$t = 3;
$s = 5;
```

And check it by PHP CodeSniffer

It produces errors:

4 | ERROR | [x] Line indented incorrectly; expected 0 spaces, found 4

8 | ERROR | [x] Line indented incorrectly; expected 0 spaces, found 4

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h68r5.png)

Sounds like a bug in Generic.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent

Сorrect processing should not give an error to this code

Comment: do you using any IDE or just run the sniffer?

Comment: Use `{...}` with `while()`. Example: `while(false) {...}`.

Comment: I need sniffer solution. My company standard in this situation defines WHILE construction without curly braces